# Stop vim-latex from opening my preamble in seperate buffer

Tags: vim-latex

How can I stop vim-latex from opening my preamble files open loading the main-file.tex? (It opens all preamble files that the mainfile calls at the beginning in a separate buffer which for me is unnecessary).